# Is there any way to delete files in Windows using a cmd script that require administrator access?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am a noob, not a programmer by any standards, so please forgive me for any wrong stuff I write here.

I use Windows 10 and made a simple batch file for clearing the temp folders (`temp`, `%temp%` and `prefetch`). I basically made a file which is like

```
cd C:\Windows\Temp
del *
cd ../Prefetch
del *
cd C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp 
del *
```

Nothing really fancy. But when I run this, first, I can't access prefetch. First I have to manually open the `Prefetch` folder and click on continue (with admin access) every time I boot up. Then I can do this. Also many files can't be accessed this way. Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: Obviously you can't delete file that **requires administrator access** without **administrator access**, so run the script as admin! Also, please use backward slashes, even though they both work in `cd`.

Comment: Is there a way I can make a .cmd file which runs as admin by default? Also, is there any way to automate this process so that this script runs as admin everytime I log in?

Comment: Do you want to bypass the prompt? You can use task scheduler and create a task that runs at startup.

Comment: Basically I get a message saying that access is denied. There is no prompt for admin access. I want to just grant it admin access everytime it runs. There is a prompt that asks for confirmation though, and I would also like to learn of a way to bypass it.

Comment: Are you admin on the machine?

Comment: Yes... I am the admin, but everytime I start the machine after shutting it down, I have to grant admin access again and again.

Comment: **USE TASK SCHEDULER**